# Use Content Source as a refiner for Search

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, search-results, search-scope

In SharePoint 2013, how do I add a refiner in the Search Refinement for the Content Source  name (as defined in Central Administration) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only refine on Managed Properties that are marked as Refinable. There is an out of the box Managed Property "ContentSource". You can try changing the Refinable attribute to Yes. You then have to run a full crawl of your content sources to populate the property. Once the crawl is complete you SHOULD be able to go into the Refiner web part and add the ContentSource property as a Refiner.

I have not tested this, but this is the general process.